# Are there any common conventions in converting between XML and JSON?

Tags: xml, json, web-services, serialization

Are there any common conventions in converting between XML and JSON when precise backward convertibility is desired?

For example I've googled to a [website](http://jsontoxml.utilities-online.info/) which adds `-` to XML tag attributes to be encoded in JSON and represents multiple same-tag XML entries as an array named exactly the tag name (in singular form), are these ways accepted any widely or specific to that website?

Comment: No. There is no standard. The formats are inequivalent. Using a `-` is a bad idea, you might encounter collisions.

Comment: See: http://www.w3.org/2005/07/xml-schema-patterns.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of conventions in use. Those that produce the most usable JSON tend to sacrifice round-tripping; those that are lossless (and can handle arbitrary XML) tend to produce JSON that is difficult to process.